# How to insert an image in javascript when calling XML data?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have data in an XML and I want to display it in a table in my HTML page.
I can display my values, and I can even display the url of my image. I thought, I just need to add the `<img>` tag, but when I add the latter, I can't see anything.

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Transporter</th><th>Type</th><th>Logo</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("transporter")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" + "<img src=\""
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("logo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "\"> </td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("transporterlist").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Do you think this is not possible?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like there is a `+` missing right after the "<img src=" part. You can also create your elements directly with javascript to avaoid the detour of string concatenation and dom parsing. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement to get started.

Comment: @lupz it's embarrassing, 1h I'm looking for other functions and it was just that. thanks a lot

Comment: That's how it is sometimes :) Happy coding